# Server 2016 File Server Best Practices

Tags: file-sharing, windows-server-2016, refs

We are going to replace our old 2008R2 file server with Server 2016.  We only have about 50 shares but about 20 TB and growing of Data.  I get the share permissions and NTFS and most restrictive which is what I keep finding when searching for best practices on windows file servers.  Questions are:

1. I am thinking of using ReFS and just mounting a drive from our SAN through VMware for every share and controlling the size of the share that way since ReFS doesn't deal with quotas. Does anybody know of a reason I definitely should not do this?
2. Does anybody have any good links for Server 2016 file server setup I have found several links for 2012 and some dead links on technet for 2016. I know there were improvements in 2016 for ReFS and I know in 2012 you shouldn't use ReFS for a file share what about 2016?

Comment: Your question is a mix of opinion polling and product/link recommendation request and, if taking the question literally, far too broad. Please read the [help].

Comment: @Sven.  I am not asking about the experience of the community.  I want to know if anybody had a definite reason not to do #1 in their experience.  Regarding #2 I can't find a good link for 2016 file server best practices.  Plenty of 2012 and some that link to 2016 on technet with dead links.  I will edit to clarify

Comment: I suggest to reformulate your question, this "best practices" thing looks like as if you wanted the answerers to write a 200 page long essay.